# Android Studio does not show method's description

Tags: android, android-studio, google-nearby

Android Studio doesn't show method's description for [Nearby API](https://developers.google.com/nearby/connections/android/get-started). If I open localhost link by hand, I will see the correct docs for every method. What's wrong? Also hyperlink on the bottom of window doesn't react to click.

[image]

> The following documentation URLs were checked:
>
> http://localhost:63342/LoudQuestion/play-services-nearby-19.1.0-javadoc.jar/com/google/android/gms/nearby/connection/ConnectionsClient.html?_ijt=7fjgr58iq9t9ccuv2i1oert1h6&_ij_reload=RELOAD_ON_SAVE#startDiscovery(java.lang.String, com.google.android.gms.nearby.connection.EndpointDiscoveryCallback

```
// gradle (module)
dependencies {
    implementation(libs.play.services.nearby)
}

// gradle (project)
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath(libs.google.services)
    }
}

// libs.versions.toml
playServicesNearby = "19.1.0"
play-services-nearby = { group = "com.google.android.gms", name = "play-services-nearby", version.ref = "playServicesNearby" }
```

**Update 1**

If go to source code, studio suggest button download sources, but proccess failed with error

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> Where: Initialization script 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\ijmiscinit4.gradle' line: 25
>
> What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:DownloadSources'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:downloadSources_5446eaaa-267c-4d7c-a8d4-6a3acc1d48f3'.
>
> Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:19.1.0@aar.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-nearby/19.1.0@aar/play-services-nearby-19.1.0@aar.pom
> - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-nearby/19.1.0@aar/play-services-nearby-19.1.0@aar.pom
>
> Required by:
> project :app

**Update 2**

There are online docs [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/nearby/connection/package-summary). But if set them by hand in the external dependencies, docs are still not displaying.

[image]